# Checking if an instance's class implements an interface?

Tags: php, interface, oop

Given a class instance, is it possible to determine if it implements a particular interface? As far as I know, there isn't a built-in function to do this directly. What options do I have (if any)?

Answer (score 322, accepted):

```
interface IInterface
{
}

class TheClass implements IInterface
{
}

$cls = new TheClass();
if ($cls instanceof IInterface) {
    echo "yes";
}
```

You can use the "instanceof" operator. To use it, the left operand is a class instance and the right operand is an interface. It returns true if the object implements a particular interface.

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php#example-124

Comment: Note that, this won't be useful if you are trying to determine constructor of the class

Answer (score 132):

As [therefromhere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8331/therefromhere) points out, you can use `class_implements()`. Just as with Reflection, this allows you to specify the class name as a string and doesn't require an instance of the class:

```php
interface IInterface
{
}

class TheClass implements IInterface
{
}

$interfaces = class_implements('TheClass');

if (isset($interfaces['IInterface'])) {
    echo "Yes!";
}
```

`class_implements()` is part of the SPL extension.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php

## Performance Tests

Some simple performance tests show the costs of each approach:

### Given an instance of an object

```
Object construction outside the loop (100,000 iterations)
 ____________________________________________
| class_implements | Reflection | instanceOf |
|------------------|------------|------------|
| 140 ms           | 290 ms     | 35 ms      |
'--------------------------------------------'

Object construction inside the loop (100,000 iterations)
 ____________________________________________
| class_implements | Reflection | instanceOf |
|------------------|------------|------------|
| 182 ms           | 340 ms     | 83 ms      | Cheap Constructor
| 431 ms           | 607 ms     | 338 ms     | Expensive Constructor
'--------------------------------------------'
```

### Given only a class name

```
100,000 iterations
 ____________________________________________
| class_implements | Reflection | instanceOf |
|------------------|------------|------------|
| 149 ms           | 295 ms     | N/A        |
'--------------------------------------------'
```

Where the expensive __construct() is:

```php
public function __construct() {
    $tmp = array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'this' => 'that'
    );  

    $in = in_array('those', $tmp);
}
```

These tests are based on [this simple code](http://pastebin.com/2xftNXip).

Answer (score 62):

nlaq points out that `instanceof` can be used to test if the object is an instance of a class that implements an interface.

But `instanceof` doesn't distinguish between a class type and an interface.  You don't know if the object is a *class* that happens to be called `IInterface`.

You can also use the reflection API in PHP to test this more specifically:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('TheClass');
if ($class->implementsInterface('IInterface'))
{
  print "Yep!\n";
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Comment: This can be used on "static" classes

Comment: See also [`class_implements()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-implements.php)

Comment: @therefromhere: Thanks, good tip.  That's part of the SPL extension.  My answer used the Reflection extension.

Comment: If you use namespaces than there won't be an ambiguousness between interfaces and classes with the same name and you can safely use `instanceof` again.

Comment: +1 for `class_implements()` since its obviously quicker to call class_implements and then in_array, instead of making a complete reflection

Answer (score 29):

## Update

The `is_a` [function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) is missing here as alternative.

I did some performance tests to check which of the stated ways is the most performant.

## Results over 100k iterations

```
      instanceof [object] took   7.67 ms | +  0% | ..........
            is_a [object] took  12.30 ms | + 60% | ................
             is_a [class] took  17.43 ms | +127% | ......................
class_implements [object] took  28.37 ms | +270% | ....................................
       reflection [class] took  34.17 ms | +346% | ............................................
```

Added some dots to actually "feel" see the difference.

Generated by this: https://3v4l.org/8Cog7

## Conclusion

In case you have an *object* to check, use `instanceof` like mentioned in the accepted answer.

In case you have a *class* to check, use `is_a`.

## Bonus

Given the case you want to instantiate a class based on an interface you require it to have, it is more preformant to use `is_a`. There is only one exception - when the constructor is empty.

Example:
`is_a(<className>, <interfaceName>, true);`

It will return `bool`. The third parameter "[allow_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php#refsect1-function.is-a-parameters)" allows it to check class names **without** instantiating the class.

Comment: This is nice, added `is_subclass_of` to the script. https://3v4l.org/FY4re

Comment: Thanks... this works and shorter than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 27):

Just to help future searches [is_subclass_of](https://www.php.net/is_subclass_of) is also a good variant (for PHP 5.3.7+):

```
if (is_subclass_of($my_class_instance, 'ISomeInterfaceName')){
    echo 'I can do it!';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also do the following

```
public function yourMethod(YourInterface $objectSupposedToBeImplementing) {
   //.....
}
```

It will throw an recoverable error if the `$objectSupposedToBeImplementing` does not implement `YourInterface` Interface.