# Array of objects: how to ensure interface

Tags: php, design-patterns, interface

Given an object:

```
class MyObject implements MyInterface
{
   public function testMethod() {

   }
}
```

If there will be another class what uses an array of objects that implment MyInterface like this:

```
class Consumer
{
    public function __construct(array $myInterfaces)
    {
         foreach($myInterfaces as $myI) {
            $myI->testMethod();
         }
    }

}
```

How can i make my program design robust where i know that I can safely call testMethod() against the array elements?

Comment: Err, is this Java or PHP?

Comment: I think language agnostic.  I added java tag as java from my opinion is very heavily based on oop and design patterns. But i had to write the example in some language

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why is there a PHP and Java snippet in there? Was exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to communicate between Java and PHP somehow?

Comment: I don't see how an answer can be language agnostic. You need to specify which language you want to implement this in.

Comment: So there is no generally accepted method of dealing with this and it is always language dependent?

Comment: Well, this problem can exist in PHP, Java, etc. when accepting an array of a base class or other interface.  That's why instanceof and related operators exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if an instance's class implements an interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274360/checking-if-an-instances-class-implements-an-interface)

Comment: Some languages support writing this, ie in Facebooks Hacklang (custom PHP) you could do `function foo(Vector<MyInterface> $listOfMyInterfaces) { }`

Comment: yes, however i was attempting to get above specific language syntax and features and consider more design patterns and strategy to deal with this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the instanceof operator.  For example:

```
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    if ($object instanceof Interface) {
        $object->testMethod();
    } else {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('All objects must implement Interface.');
    }
}
```

In some languages, there are typed arrays, which can enforce this (such as Java.)  The above is an example for PHP which does not have typed arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP use the `class_implements('MyObject')` and cycle through the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of type hinting (type references) like so:

```
class Consumer {

    public function __construct(array $myInterfaces) {
        foreach ($myInterfaces as $myI) {
            $this->process($myI);
        }
    }

    private function process(MyInterface $m) {
        $m->testMethod();
    }

}
```

So to avoid a fatal error, process() will have to get an instance of MyInterface and by extension constructor argument has to be a collection of MyInterfaces.

You've effectively type constrained the collection constructor receives.

Comment: php7 would actually make process() throw a TypeError exception in case of a wrong type passed which gives a chance to your constructor to throw an exception with an appropriate error message describing whats wrong with the collection it got.