# How to check an instance implements an interface

Tags: typescript, express

In PHP we can check it like following. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274360/checking-if-an-instances-class-implements-an-interface?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
interface IInterface
{
}

class TheClass implements IInterface
{
}

$cls = new TheClass();
if ($cls instanceof IInterface) {
    echo "yes";
}
```

Same way I want to check it in Typescript. I have done like this.

```
public handle() {

        return (err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: any) => {

            switch (err.constructor) {

                case MyException:
                    var response = err.getResponse();
                    res.status(500).send(response);
                    break;
                default:
                    res.status(500).send(err.message);

            }
        }
 }
```

Instead of `MyException` I want to check `IMyException`. How can I do this?

Comment: *Instead of MyException I want to check IMyException* - what is the reasoning behind this, by the way? This may affect how the case should be handled.

Comment: If I use the another class "YourException" which implements "IMyException", then I have to explicitly check the instance. If I use interface type checking we dont need to change the code.

Comment: Yes, it won't be an instance of this class then. You have to duck-type it like usually it's done in JS (not TS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces don't exist at runtime. 
TypeScript interfaces only guarantee [structural compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html). Class instance that is supposed to conform a type (e.g. `err: MyException`) shouldn't necessarily be an instance of the class of the same name (prototypically inherit from it).

In order for an interface to be used at runtime, it should be a class. If a class isn't supposed to be instantiated for some reason, it should be abstract, and concrete class should inherit from it:

```
abstract class BaseMyException {
  ...
}

class MyException extends BaseMyException {}
```

Then it can be asserted to be an instance of this class with `err instanceof BaseMyException`. Notice that `err.constructor` checks only own constructor.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible in TypeScript because interfaces only exist at compile time.